# Python dumps variable from loop

Tags: python

Total bottles variable in the getBottles module resets to 0 upon exiting the while counter <8 loop. I've also tried using return statements but to no avail. How do I get the value from totalBottles variable to pass to my other module.

```
global totalBottles, totalPayout, todayBottles
totalBottles=0 #store the accumulated bottle values
counter=1 #will control the loop
todayBottles=0 #store the number of bottles returned on a day
totalPayout=0 #store the calculated value of totalBottles x.10

def main():
    keepGoing='y'

    while keepGoing =='y':
        getBottles (totalBottles, todayBottles, counter)
        calcPayout (totalBottles, totalPayout)
        printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout)
        keepGoing == raw_input ('Do you want to run the program again?')

def getBottles (totalBottles, todayBottles, counter):
    while counter <8:
        todayBottles = input ('Enter number of bottles returned for the day:')
        totalBottles = todayBottles + totalBottles
        counter=counter + 1

def calcPayout(totalBottles, totalPayout):
    totalPayout = totalBottles * .10

def printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout):
    print totalBottles,('is the total bottles')
    print totalPayout, ('amount due')

main()
```

Comment: This is... almost unbelievable... I'm honestly surprised!

Comment: I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Sorry but this problem has been bugging me since lastnight. I really want to figure this out. How would you handle getting the number out. I am a beginner and was referred to ask online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use global variables, you have to specify this in the function also :

```
global totalBottles, totalPayout, todayBottles
totalBottles=0 #store the accumulated bottle values
counter=1 #will control the loop
todayBottles=0 #store the number of bottles returned on a day
totalPayout=0 #store the calculated value of totalBottles x.10

def main():
    global totalBottles, totalPayout, todayBottles
    keepGoing='y'

    while keepGoing =='y':
        getBottles (counter)
        calcPayout ()
        printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout)
        keepGoing == raw_input ('Do you want to run the program again?')

def getBottles (counter):
    global totalBottles, todayBottles
    while counter <8:
        todayBottles = input ('Enter number of bottles returned for the day:')
        totalBottles = todayBottles + totalBottles
        counter=counter + 1

def calcPayout():
    global totalBottles, totalPayout, todayBottles
    totalPayout = totalBottles * .10

def printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout):
    print totalBottles,('is the total bottles')
    print totalPayout, ('amount due')

main()
```

otherwise you could use return values :

```
global totalBottles, totalPayout, todayBottles
totalBottles=0 #store the accumulated bottle values
counter=1 #will control the loop
todayBottles=0 #store the number of bottles returned on a day
totalPayout=0 #store the calculated value of totalBottles x.10

def main():

    keepGoing='y'
    while keepGoing =='y':
        totalBottles = getBottles(totalBottles, todayBottles)
        totalPayout = calcPayout (totalBottles)
        printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout)
        keepGoing == raw_input ('Do you want to run the program again?')

def getBottles (totalBottles, todayBottles):
    counter=1
    while counter <8:
        todayBottles = input ('Enter number of bottles returned for the day:')
        totalBottles = todayBottles + totalBottles
        counter=counter + 1
    return totalBottles

def calcPayout(totalBottles):
    totalPayout = totalBottles * .10
    return totalPayout

def printInfo(totalBottles, totalPayout):
    print totalBottles,('is the total bottles')
    print totalPayout, ('amount due')

main()
```

Comment: `def getBottles (totalBottles, todayBottles, counter):
    global totalBottles, todayBottles` will cause an error, because you're declaring totalBottles and todayBottles as both a local and global variable. `SyntaxError: name 'totalBottles' is local and global`

Answer (score 1):

i can't resist... (although there are still issues with this at least it might work where the other won't)

```
class Bottles:
    def __init__(self):
       self.totalBottles=0 #store the accumulated bottle values
       self.counter=1 #will control the loop
       self.todayBottles=0 #store the number of bottles returned on a day
       self.totalPayout=0 #store the calculated value of totalBottles x.10

    def getBottles(self):
        while self.counter <8:
            self.todayBottles = input ('Enter number of bottles returned for the day:')
            self.totalBottles = self.todayBottles + self.totalBottles
            self.counter=self.counter + 1

    def calcPayout(self):
        self.totalPayout = self.totalBottles * .10

    def printInfo(self):
        print self.totalBottles,('is the total bottles')
        print self.totalPayout, ('amount due')

def main():
    keepGoing='y'

    while keepGoing =='y':
        b = Bottles()
        b.getBottles()
        b.calcPayout()
        b.printInfo()
        keepGoing == raw_input ('Do you want to run the program again?')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be scope related? It seems you have declared global variables and then pass them around in your method calls. I wonder if it is confused, using a local totalBottles instead of the global one. Try this without passing around your global variables.

Comment: Dang, I was just about to post this :-(
I actually tested it out, and if you have all the methods like `def getBottles (totalBottles, todayBottles, counter): ...` be `def getBottles(): global totalBottles, todayBottles, counter`, it works

Answer (score 0):

Using `global` in the global namespace does nothing. If you want to update a global from inside a function, you have to use it there:

```
def calcPayout():
    global totalPayout
    totalPayout = totalBottles * .10 # now the global gets updated
```

You have to do this to all your functions.

The much, much saner way is to use return:

```
def calcPayout(totalBottles):
    return totalBottles * .10

totalPayout = calcPayout(totalBottles)
```